# Configured Hadoop but not able to get responce from hive?

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop, hive

I am working on Hive, i configure hive on my ubuntu ( Linux master 3.2.0-48-generic #74-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jun 6 19:43:26 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux) machine and hadoop but when i try to make database in hive then i get following error:

My **error** is:

```
FAILED: Error in metadata: MetaException(message:Got exception:java.io.FileNotFoundException File file:/user/hive/warehouse/foo does not exist.)
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask
```

Comment: `file:/user/hive/warehouse/foo` doesn't exists is pretty clear, isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

configuire your hadoop properly and edit your core-site.xml mapred-site.xml and hdfs-site.xml and export your path of hive in .bashrc